# Which Documentum APIs should I use?

Tags: documentum

There seems to be a number of options for interfacing to Documentum; WDK, DMCL, DFC, DFS, DQL, etc.

What else is there?
When whould you use which interface? For .NET developers, for Java developers?

Answer (score 11):

- WDK is for making websites.
- DMCL is an old api for communicating with Documentum, in last versions it's only present as an emulation layer, so it should be avoided.
- DFC is the preferred API to interact with Documentum, provides all functionality.
- DFS is for using Documentum from webservices.
- DQL is for querying, it's SQL-like.

DFC and WDK are Java, the others are probably usable from .Net

Comment: a link for general documentum development information: [http://www.dmdeveloper.com/]

Answer (score 8):

David provides a good overview but to expand a bit...

DFC is the base Java api for interacting with Documentum.  WDK is actually built on top of DFC.  The DMCL is the legacy api built in C(or C++ I'm not 100% sure).  Prior to D6, all DFC calls used the DMCL under the covers but that layer was rewritten in java for D6 and the DMCL is there just to provide backwards compatibility at this point.

As for accessing Documentum via .NET there is a Documentum PIA that you can use to access the DFC libraries from a .Net project rather than using the traditional Java route.

Answer (score 3):

You could also consider using the CMIS (Content Management Interoperability Services) interface that's being developed for Documentum. It's a web service interface that expands upon AtomPub. It won't be able to leverage all the bells and whistles of the Documentum platform, but it should allow you to use other backends like  Alfresco and SharePoint.  There's an Early Access Release available via EMC for Documentum.

Answer (score 3):

Massive operation, like bulk upload, you must use DFC, because some feature are accesible only via DFC.

Web operation, I suggest the use of DFS, with is own caching system (can be a problem) and session manager.

The code is more decoupled using DFS instead using of DFC.

DFC use is deprecated, but at the moment you cannot have the same result using DFS.

There is also some technical difference: for example DFC is RMI shared object, so the object is connect to the content server. Instead DFS after web service give you the object, the object is disconnect from content server.

In DFC you have to manage Session, connection, and so many other things tipical of RMI.

DQL is only a way to make query, and so other basic operation on Documentum.

Answer (score 2):

Both David and shsteimer is right.

But Documentum PIA for .Net is not encouraged now because it will be deprecated in future edition of Documentum.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information (future deprecation)?

Answer (score 1):

I just found this old discussion, but based on the following link, the "EMC Documentum REST Services" is something to consider:

https://community.emc.com/community/edn/documentum/blog/2013/06/22/announcing-emc-documentum-rest-services-70